# How can I add elements from one collection that do not exist in a second collection to a third collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 generic lists:

```
List<string> input
List<string> compareTo
List<string> results
```

I'd like to take the list of input and compare each value to the compare list, and if it doesn't exist add it to the results list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any reason you can't just use LINQ?

```
List<string> results = input.Except(compareTo).ToList();
```

Comment: no there is no reason, and very nice. i probably should have said 1 linq statement.

Comment: He wants to add it to results, implying there may already be something there, so maybe `results.AddRange(input.Except())`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Possibly - although in my experience you *rarely* need to do this sort of thing with an existing list.

Answer (score 4):

```
compareTo.ForEach( x => {

    if(!input.Contains(x))results.Add(x); 


    });
```